# ksoap2-android eclipse import

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I added the library like how google explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary). If i debugg throug the app in the emulator i get the error: "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file SoapObject.class." Whats that? If i click Change Attached Source i can chose the .jar file again...and the error is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the jar there's no source code, so you can't actually go through those code lines when debugging, like it happens when you're executing your own code. it's just normal.

Comment: But how can i debug then? I cant go further if those error comes?

Comment: If some error happens in there, the problem is for the library developer, or because of misuse (or bad design?) of the library. In the best case you should get some exception with a message. In the worst (and you want to debug the library) you might be able to get that source code. Sadly I have no experience in this.